# How to declare this algorithm?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to declare an algorithm that takes a pair of iterators and a criterium. It then returns a vector of items from the range of the iterators which fulfil the criterium.

```
template <typename TIterator, typename TCriterium>
std::vector< Type that I will get after dereferencing TIterator >
filter (TIterator begin, TIterator end, TCriterium passes);
```

I can use C++11 features such as decltype or auto. I tried:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename TIterator, typename TCriterium>
auto filter (TIterator begin, TIterator end, TCriterium passes) 
                      -> std::vector< decltype(*begin) >
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> vector;
    filter(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:59: 
error: forming pointer to reference type 'int*&'
```

Comment: Note that [˙copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) behaves almost the same, only that you need to pass an output iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type>
```

As the return type of your function, which would then become:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// ...

template <typename TIterator, typename TCriterium>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type> filter(
    TIterator begin, TIterator end, TCriterium passes)
{
    // Body...
}
```

If you want to go the `decltype` way, then you could do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// ...

template <typename TIterator, typename TCriterium>
auto filter (TIterator begin, TIterator end, TCriterium passes)
    -> std::vector< typename std::decay<decltype(*begin)>::type >
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This indeed compiles and works as I want it to work.

Comment: But that will fail if `TIterator` is a real pointer (`int*`). What about using `std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type`?

Comment: What happens if I call filter(myrange.cbegin(), myrange.cend(), ...)? Do I end up with a vector<const T> in the first case? That would not be nice.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: No, `value_type` would not be `const` - see the non-firing `static_assert` in [this example](http://ideone.com/0KwpI7)

Answer (score 2):

`*begin` is a reference, so you'll need to remove that:

```
-> std::vector< std::remove_reference<decltype(*vector)>::type >
```

although, having read the other answers, I'd probably prefer to use `iterator_traits` here.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) and the type_traits header for manipulating types

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type>` or possibly `std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(*begin)>::type>`. I would prefer the former.

Comment: Why would you advice `std::decay` rather than `std::remove_reference` ? It seems slightly "overpowered".

Comment: If the passed iterator is a const_iterator, operator* returns a const T&, and remove_reference will turn that into a const T. You don't want a vector<const T>. Come to think of it, iterator_traits::value_type might be const for const_iterators too.

Comment: Ah! I had not thought about `const`-ness issues. I don't think the `value_type` would be `const` though. They typically are "bare", probably for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to get the type used by the iterator:

```
template <typename TIterator, typename TCriterium>
auto filter (TIterator begin, TIterator end, TCriterium passes) 
                  -> std::vector<std::iterator_traits<TIterator>::value_type>
```